# MongoDB bulk lookup by bson_id

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I'm using Neo4j for a large graph of data, and using MongoDB to store detailed document information about individual nodes.

I need to be able to take the results of my graph traversals (sometimes up to 1000 bson_ids) and query Mongo for them.  I've noticed that even with selects and limits, the performance isn't great.

Any ideas on how I can make this mapping more efficient?

Comment: Can you provide some details on how you're doing your queries? Are you using the `$in` command? How large are the 1000 documents you're returning. If you're returning 1000 docs and they're each one MB in size, that's going to affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I have no advice regarding fast mongo document retrieval. Perhaps the [$in](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in) operator helps.

Are you querying mongo directly too on other occasions ? Or are you just querying the graph? Then perhaps you could also either serialize your documents directly to node properties. Or even better represent them in the graph - graph databases are a superset of document databases anyway. (document being described aggregate root node and its tree of dependend nodes or a dynamic document which is defined with a traversal - see the [neo4j spatial dynamic layers](http://www.slideshare.net/craigtaverner/neo4j-spatial-backing-a-gis-with-a-true-graph-database)) Other people use graph databases for document centric applications and engines too (e.g. the [structr](http://structr.org) CMS on Neo4j)

Comment: Also, have a look at [Square Pegs and Round Holes in the NOSQL World](http://jim.webber.name/2011/04/21/e2f48ace-7dba-4709-8600-f29da3491cb4.aspx) by Jim Webber regarding document dbs and graphdbs.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and the article in the comment here is great.  Thanks for the tips, I've been inspired